# Adobe CQ 6 component in targeting mode - UI issue

Tags: adobe, aem, sightly

I have been creating a site using sightly. But when I try to make content targeting for my component I’m watching a strange behavior. All  html nodes which are placed above the component remove entirely from the html layout and css styles are broken  in targeting mode. The same behavior is watched when this component is placed into some Geometrixx page. At the same time other Geometrixx components on the page work fine.
Can it be related with using sightly?  Does sightly work correct for content targeting?

Comment: Do you mean that the component breaks when you actually target it or when you switch the editor to "Target mode"?

Comment: I mean that the component breaks when I switch the editor to "Target mode".

Comment: May be this is some known issue of Sightly? I do not know.

Comment: The broken layout could be caused by a backend error. As far as I can remember, the OOTB _Target_ integration creates a copy of your component's content at a different path under `/content/campaigns`. You might be facing these problems if the code invoked in your Sightly scripts is somehow dependent on the content structure outside its containing page. I've seen such behaviour in AEM 5.6.1 while using JSP, which tends to render more readable errors.